# How do i add two more sections to 'UPLOAD' attachments?

Tags: php

just wondering if anyone could help me please, i am trying to add two more more sections on our corporate site which will allow us to have people uploading more than one attachments. Could anyone help please?

```
 <?php
    /**
     * @package 
     * @copyright Copyright (c)2010 
     * @license GNU General Public License version 2, or later
     */

        defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');  // {}
        if($this->config->allow_unsolicited == 0) die(JText::_('UNSOLAPPL_NOT_ALLOWED'));
    ?>
    <?php $layout = JRequest::getVar('lyt', ''); ?>
    <?php if($this->errors > 0) : ?>
       <?php $option='com_jobboard'; $app= JFactory::getApplication(); ?>
       <?php $fields = $app->getUserState('fields');   ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $req_marker = '*'; ?>
             <?php $path = 'index.php?option='. $option.'&view=upload&task=uload'; ?>
              <form method="post" action="<?php echo JRoute::_($path); ?>" id="applFRM" name="applFRM" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div id="aplpwrapper">
                  <?php echo JText::_('UPLOAD_CV_RESUME'); ?>
                  <h3><?php echo JText::_('UNSOLICITED_SUBMISSION'); ?></h3>
                  <div id="contleft">
                     <p><strong><?php echo JText::_('NOTE') ?>: </strong><?php echo JText::_('UNSOLICITED_CV_NOTIFICATION'); ?></p>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <label for="first_name"><?php echo JText::_('FIRSTNAME'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                        <input class="inputfield " maxlength="20" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="50" value="<?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->first_name: ''; ?>" type="text" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <label for="last_name"><?php echo JText::_('LASTNAME'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                        <input class="inputfield " maxlength="20" id="last_name" name="last_name" size="50" value="<?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->last_name: ''; ?>" type="text" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <label for="email"><?php echo JText::_('EMAIL_ADDRESS'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                        <input class="inputfield " maxlength="50" id="email" name="email" size="50" value="<?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->email: ''; ?>" type="text" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <label for="tel"><?php echo JText::_('TELEPHONE'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                        <input class="inputfield " maxlength="50" id="tel" name="tel" size="50" value="<?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->tel: ''; ?>" type="text" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <label for="title"><?php echo JText::_('CV_RESUME_TITLE'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                        <input class="inputfield " id="title" name="title" size="50" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->title: ''; ?>" type="text" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="rowsep">&nbsp;</div>
                     <div class="controw">
                        <div class="uplrow">
                          <label for="cv"><?php echo JText::_('CV_RESUME'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                          <input class="inputfield " maxlength="199" name="cv" id="cv" size="38" type="file" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="fslabel">
                          <small><strong><?php echo JText::_('NB'); ?>:</strong><?php echo '&nbsp;'.JText::_('UPLOAD_ONLY_FORMATTYPES'); ?></small>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="rowsep"> <h4><?php echo JText::_('OPTIONAL') ?></h4>
                        <label for="cover_text"><?php echo JText::_('COVER_NOTE') ?></label> <br /><small><?php echo JText::_('COVER_NOTE_HINT'); ?>:</small>
                        <textarea rows="4" id="cover_text" cols="" name="cover_text" style="float: right; margin-right: 12%; width: 47%;padding-top:5px" ><?php echo ($this->errors > 0)? $fields->cover_note: ''; ?></textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div align="center" style="clear: both; padding-top: 15px">
                          <span id="loadr" class="hidel"></span><input id="submit_application" name="submit_application" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo JText::_('SUBMIT_APPLICATION') ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" class="button" type="Submit">
                          <?php $show_list='index.php?option='. $option.'&view=list&catid=1&lyt='.$layout; ?>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_($show_list); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('BACK'); ?></a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <input name="form_submit" value="submitted" type="hidden">
              <input name="catid" value="<?php echo $this->catid; ?>" type="hidden">
              <?php echo JHTML::_('form.token'); ?>
              </form>
     <?php echo $this->setstate; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just duplicate code from line 45 to line 53:

```
             <div class="controw">
                <div class="uplrow">
                  <label for="cv"><?php echo JText::_('CV_RESUME'); ?><span class="fieldreq"><?php echo $req_marker; ?></span></label>
                  <input class="inputfield " maxlength="199" name="cv" id="cv" size="38" type="file" />
                </div>
                <div id="fslabel">
                  <small><strong><?php echo JText::_('NB'); ?>:</strong><?php echo '&nbsp;'.JText::_('UPLOAD_ONLY_FORMATTYPES'); ?></small>
                </div>
             </div>
```

as many time as you need (eg 2).

and change

```
name="cv"
```

to

```
name="cv[]"
```

Then when you process submit just use $_FILES['cv'] as array.
For details see official PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php